# How to Play Transparent background avi file in media element?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mediaelement

I have a video with transparent background in .avi format (Made from Adobe After Effects), but the transparent background appears black in mediaelement. Media Player has no background property also.

What should i use so that this media element plays the file and when placed on an image takes that image as its background. (No i cannot embed that image in the avi file as my image keeps changing).

*If my approach is wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid using the normal wpf media player this can't be done.

The mediaplayer ignores the transparent regions, even with video formats that accept it.  From memory, i dont think AVI files support transparent regions.  MOV files do.

Having said that, and although it could be a very complicated task, it may be possible to enhance the WPFMediaKit mediaplayer to do what you want.

http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/

J Morrill the author of wpfmediakit may be able to let you know if it is possible or not.

I might add that i got around this problem in a project once by using a sequence of .png files that played a short 10 second movie.  Of course this is not an ideal solution, but it got me out of a jam

Comment: I did as u suggested. i had 60 PNG images of 2 second animation. Using DispatcherTimer class i changed an image source after every 333333 ticks (1,00,00,000 * 2/60 Ticks)

* 1,00,00,000 is the number of ticks in a second.

Comment: it seems the WPFMediaKit can not do this.

Comment: Yep, WPF-MediaKit cannot play transparent movs, see https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/issues/45

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use color keying - assing a color (or more colors) in your video, which you translate to the transparency by a WPF `Effect`(`BitmapEffect` or `ShaderEffect`).