# Use XAML animation to load different images as an animation?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

In my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470507/how-to-play-transparent-background-avi-file-in-media-element) question, i asked how to play transparent AVI Files in media element. I was advised to have transparent PNG Files load in sequence so that it looks like an animation.

I achieved this by doing this:

I have 60 PNG images making 2 second animation. Using DispatcherTimer class i changed an image source after every 333333 ticks (1,00,00,000 * 2/60 Ticks)

*Note: 1,00,00,000 is the number of ticks in a second

I want to do this as an animation in XAML? How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "as a double animation"?

Implementing this in pure XAML will be extremely verbose given that each PNG image would have to be declared as a resource, and loaded explicitly in a storyboard. Eg:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="MyButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Frame1Image}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.03" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Frame2Image}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.06" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Frame3Image}"/>
            <!-- etc -->
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>             
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```