# How can I play a video with alpha channel (transparency)?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, video-processing

Is it possible to play videos with transparency in `MediaElement` or `MediaPlayer` (C# WPF)
with a background at the back so the background would appear in the transparent areas of the videos?

I researched for an answer but couldn't find any, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate? Did you see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8470507/945456)?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid MediaElement does not preserve the information necessary. However, color-keying is probably the easiest solution.

You need to create a video where transparent sections are turned into 127,127,127(RGB) and later change them to transparent in shader.

The shader can look something like this:

```
sampler2D input : register(s0); 

bool equals(float f1, float f2) 
{ 
    float f = abs(f1 - f2); 
    return f < 0.0001f; 
} 

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{    
    float4 result = tex2D(input, uv);     

    if( (equals(result.r, 127)) && 
        (equals(result.g, 127)) && 
        (equals(result.b, 127)) ) 
    { 
        // make transparent?!
        result.r = 0; 
        result.g = 0; 
        result.b = 0; 
        result.a = 0; 
    } 

    return result; 
}
```